# Python modules not found post upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, python, ipython

I've been using ipython, pandas and various other libraries in Ubuntu 16.04 for a very long time. I've recently upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 (Upgraded to 18.04 and then to 20.04 quickly).

In both 18.04 and 20.04, when I try to run ipython I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/ipython3", line 6, in 
from IPython import start_ipython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'

ipython is in /usr/local/bin/ipython3. That inturn seems to have '#!/usr/bin/python3'.

Clearly /usr/bin/python3 is not seeing the ipython install.

Now in ubuntu 20.04 /usr/bin/python3 is python3.8. IIRC, In 16.04 it used to be python python3.5.

Originally ipython and various other modules were installed when I was in 16.04. So I am assuming these would have installed it into the python3.5... and the current python3 doesn't see them.

Questions:

1. Is my reasoning above correct?
2. Does this mean now in ubuntu 20.04 I should reinstall all modules I need afresh (so that they would go into python3.8)
3. If I have to reinstall modules, Is it safe to remove the earlier ipython or other modules that I had installed in 16.04? How would I know if some modules among these are used by the rest of the system
4. In general, a user in ubuntu when installing modules, should he do a 'sudo pip install' or just a 'pip install'.
5. Currently when I check /usr/bin/python*, there seems to be several installations:
   /usr/bin/python2.7
   /usr/bin/python3.5
   /usr/bin/python3.5m
   /usr/bin/python3.8

Are all these required by the system (i.e., ubuntu 20.04) or are some of these leftovers from ubuntu 16.04 that I can safely remove?

Comment: Leave the system Python installations alone, unless youknow what you're doing.  If you've upgraded, Python will default to 3.8 and that will result in your previous modules not working - you will need to reinstall those modules.

Comment: Problem is I don't know which are the system python installations and what modules they require. For instance - I know that I installed ipython in 16.04, so that is probably not the system. So if I reinstall ipython.. I suppose this would overwrite the current /usr/local/bin/ipython.. leading two installations of ipython that may be overwriting/corrupting each other?

Comment: If you did any types of installation in /usr/local/ those are manually installed by you and need rebuilt/reinstalled/recompiled.  Leave anything not in `/usr/local` alone.  You may want to run `sudo apt autoremove` at some point to try and clean up unneeded packages (which may remove the older Python)

Comment: Thank you. But I did not manually install in those locations - that much I'm sure. In 16.04, IIRC, all that I had done was pip3 install ipython. So if the ipython is in /usr/local/bin its probably that installation that put it there. (Also, I did the sudo apt autoremove ..didn't remove anything.)